# CucumberJS script errors

Tags: javascript, react-native, cucumberjs

I'm new to `cucumber`, so I don't know if my issue is derived from lack of understanding, or if it's actually an error with the script (not likely I would think). So, I'll just relate what's happening. In general, when I run `cucumber`, I get the feature/scenario output, but the script throws errors later in the execution. I read that this may be caused by an error in my `feature` or `steps_definition` files, but I don't know what to look for.

I have the package installed as a dependency

```
  "dependencies": {
    "cucumber": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native": "0.54.1",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1"
  }
```

and set in my `scripts` object

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "jest": "jest",
    "cucumber": "cucumber-js",
    "gjest": "gherkin-jest",
    "jestc": "jest-cucumber"
  }
```

My feature file (located in `/features`) reads:

```
Feature: Create a new member account
  As a new member
  I want to create a member account

Scenario: Create a new user
  When I create a new user with details:
    | Username | mstelly              |
    | Email    | my.email@example.com |
    | Password | mySecretPassword     |
  Then the user is created successfully
```

My step_definitions file (located in `/features/step_definitions`) reads:

```
    const { Given, Then, When } = require('cucumber');
    const expect = require('expect');

    When('I create a new user with details:', function(table) {
      const data = table.rowsHash();
      JSON.stringify(data);
    });

    Then('the user is created successfully', function() {
      // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
      return 'pending';
    });
```

When I execute the script: `npm run cucumber features -r step_definitions/`, I receive the following console output:

```
> mobile_gtm@0.0.1 cucumber /Users/michaelstelly/Documents/projects/mobile_gtm
> cucumber-js "features" "step_definitions/"

.P

Warnings:

1) Scenario: Create a new user # features/accountCreate.feature:5
   ✔ When I create a new user with details: # features/step_definitions/accountCreate.steps.js:4
       | Username | mstelly              |
       | Email    | my.email@example.com |
       | Password | mySecretPassword     |
   ? Then the user is created successfully # features/step_definitions/accountCreate.steps.js:9
       Pending

1 scenario (1 pending)
2 steps (1 pending, 1 passed)
0m00.001s
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mobile_gtm@0.0.1 cucumber: `cucumber-js "features" "step_definitions/"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mobile_gtm@0.0.1 cucumber script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/michaelstelly/.npm/_logs/2018-03-29T11_57_24_218Z-debug.log
```

That's all the information I have. I receive the cucumber output, but then I get the `npm` errors. They may have nothing to do with cucumber, but at this point, I can't be sure.

Help is appreciated. If you have questions, please ask.

Comment: Please do mention at which line it is pointing the error. It might have mentioned the line which is encountering error

Comment: @Mandy8055 I posted everything on the console. There were no line numbers in the error message. For reference, the same script fails using `yarn cucumber`. Finally, I learned that if all tests pass, the error is not thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is supposed to happen. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/843#issuecomment-305331023

> cucumber-js exits with status 1 if there are any undefined / pending / failed / ambiguous steps. It exits with status 0 if all steps pass.

I know this question is old, but I ran across this trying to find an answer to my own question and hope that this will help The Future.